# Assert.AreEqual<T> (and Related Generic Functions) Don't Enforce Their Argument Types

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, type-conversion

I am writing some unit tests, well actually I'm fixing unit tests after a refactor, and I noticed some very odd behavior. The original assertion used the non-generic flavor of the AreEqual method.

```
Assert.AreEqual(Foo.Do(...), Bar.Do(...).Conversion(...));
```

After some refactoring, Foo.Do() no longer returned the same type and needed additional conversion to maintain the equivalence. However, the AreEquals function happily takes any objects so the tests failed at run-time instead of compile-time like one would hope.

So, I decided to change the assertions to their generic counterparts to enforce that changes like this in the future would turn into compile-time errors.

```
Assert.AreEqual<X>(Foo.Do(...), Bar.Do(...).Conversion(...));
```

At this point, I haven't changed Foo.Do() to return the correct type, so I should get a compile error that Foo.Do()'s return is not a X. To my surprise, nothing happens. The compile succeeds just fine. I assume there must be an implicit conversion between the types somewhere, but a little experimenting shows there isn't. I have tried a few other mock examples to see if having non-generic and generic flavors of functions would interact this way, but I can't reproduce this behavior except with this class.

Why does the compiler not enforce that both values be of type X, even if that is what it appears to imply if you hover over the function in Visual Studio?

Comment: Can you post a minimal version of your `X` class (and perhaps the class of the return value of Foo.Do()) that reproduces this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of frustrating searching, I did end up finding an implicit cast in a set of extension methods that were being pulled in by another line of code in a different test completely unrelated to the types at hand. I have since talked with the person that put in that hack. Another implicit conversion fail.